# Javascript variable is not updating inside function

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, javascript-scope

```js
let number = 100
 
function change(number) {
    number = number * 10;
}
 
change(number);
 
console.log(number);
```

The above code outputs 100, whereas

```js
let number = 100
 
function change(blah) {
    number = number * 10;
}
 
change(number);
 
console.log(number);
```

outputs 1000
Can someone explain why the number is not updating its value inside the function when the parameter name is also "number"?

Comment: When you name your parameter `blah`, `number` is not defined anywhere inside the function, so it refers to the global variable. When you name the parameter as `number`, it becomes a local variable, which won't affect the global one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Also [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet creates a local variable `number` as the function parameter which shadows the outer variable of the same name.

Since JavaScript is pass by value the new variable is assigned the value `100`. Since the variable is scoped to the function `change` and when you update the assignment, the variable defined in the function scope is updated.

```
let number = 100
 
function change(number) {
    //This is the variable scoped to the function
    number = number * 10;
}
//This is the variable defined in the global scope
change(number);
 
console.log(number);
```

In the second snippet, you are updating the `number` defined outside the function`change` directly, hence you see the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, the parameter **hides** the `number` variable - it creates a variable called `number` which is local to the function, and then updates it.

In the second snippet, the parameter isn't even used, and the `number` variable is updated directly. You could have written the same function without a parameter:

```js
let number = 100
 
function change() { // No parameter!
    number = number * 10;
}
 
change();
 
console.log(number);
```

Comment: If `change` has no params, why are you passing a param in when you invoke it?

Comment: @mwilson good catch - a poor copy-paste from the OP's code. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables with the same name as the parameters, as the value **will be the same anyway**, unless the variable with the same name **will have a different value than the parameter** this is because the function's parameters are already declared as local for this function.